# Reading/Accessing Spark stream batch start time during batch processing

Tags: apache-spark, batch-file, time, stream, streaming

I have spiky streaming data and every so often, the batches will back up and eventually, they clear through. I'm fine with that performance, but my reporting requires being able to access the batch 'start time' (at least roughly). I've been looking for it, but only find it on the Spark Console, listing the 'Streaming' batches (pending/current/past all have a 'batch time'). It must be available somewhere (tried DStream structure to a reasonable extent). Is there some magic I've been missing?

There is a 'context' start time, but that is the start time of the Streaming Context only and never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Update**: I found that adding a Streaming Listener to record the batch time in the 'onBatchStarted' method was what I needed. I used that value in a Broadcast variable in the callback to make the batch start time available for all executors. Simple solution.

**Background**: I am converting streaming data into time series data. Using the current time for a batch works if you never fall behind in processing. When a big batch of data hits and things back up, the benefits of direct streams from Kafka make it simple to process a backlog, but then the current system time is no longer useful. This is where having a connection to the actual batch time is valuable.

Answer (score 1):

@Robert Wyatt,

What you are looking for is `structured streaming` **monitoring**

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#monitoring-streaming-queries